# Finding Tangent Vectors with an Implicitly Defined Function Without Using the Concept of the Gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function

After finishing up the section called Tangent Planes and Linear Approximations, I thought I knew the material, until I began working on the first problem.

This portion of the exercise reads as follows:

> For the following exercises, as a useful review of techniques used in this section, find a normal vector and a tangent vector at the point $P$.

This section never covered tangent vectors. Not only that, but this book has not touched finding vectors using implicitly defined functions. Here is the implicitly defined curve

$$x^2 + xy + y^2 - 3 = 0$$

and we want to find the normal and tangent vectors at the point $(-1,-1)$.

I don't understand what's going on or how to approach this problem. This section is before the concept of a gradient, which I heard would help in solving this problem, but I want to try and understand what to do with the given information independent from the gradient.

**Question**
I would like to know the intuition behind solving this problem, because I think if I had that, I would at least know want I'm supposed to be building instead of taking derivatives aimlessly. In fact, using implicit differentiation and evaluating the derivative at $(-1,-1)$, I get

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -1$$

But I don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you pretend you could draw the graph, it would maybe look like this, right? (Ignore the coordinate axes)

[image: tangent line]

Maybe i drew the curve wrong, but I got the tangent line correct, right?

What I'm trying to say is, as long as $dy/dx$ makes sense, it is indeed the gradient of the tangent line to the curve at that point.

Once I know a tangent vector, I can find a normal vector by rotation.